# Can I setup hive metastore w/o hadoop on aws and use RDS as db

Tags: hive, metastore

want to have central hive meta store to consume from databrick, spectrum etc ..

Is it possible to setup w/o installing hadoop

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Hive metastore installation does not require Hadoop.

Querying data from the Hive metastore requires a Hive client (within Spark) and a Hadoop compatible filesystem (such as S3)

AWS Glue Data Catalog is the recommended system nowadays, not RDS